# Different results of UTF-8 encoding to URL parameter with particular languages between RawUrl and QueryString in HttpRequest

Tags: c#, utf-8, httprequest, request.querystring, rawurl

**Update - 31 Aug**

```
string test = "ö";
string unicode1 = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(test, Encoding.Unicode);
string unicode2 = HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode(test);
Console.WriteLine("Result of unicode1: " + unicode1);
Console.WriteLine("Result of unicode2: " + unicode2);
```

we can see the different results. now the case is when i was using UrlEncode the parameter in URL for posting the data, it returns would become unicode2 when the browser is getting the resources.

**Update - 30 Aug** [please click the link to see the tracing httprequest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCwoV.png)
it was strange that the value of the parameter "nm" in QueryString became different, its original string was "ööö", so we can see it in Url, after encoding by UTF-8, it became "%c3%b6%c3%b6%c3%b6%" in RawUrl, in normal case, it should keep the same result of encoding between RawUrl and QueryString. Does anyone know the reason?

I encountered an issue that the URL referrer will become to null after clicking the button.
I filled in the text "öööööööö", you can see the different encoding between c# and IE.

[the url encoded by c#, it was captured by Fiddler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgdSy.jpg)

[the url encoded by IE, it was displayed in IE status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjZ8D.jpg)

Result of encoding by UTF8: “%c3%b6%c3%b6%c3%b6%c3%b6%c3%b6%c3%b6%c3%b6%c3%b6”

Result of encoding by IE: “%u00f6%u00f6%u00f6%u00f6%u00f6%u00f6%u00f6%u00f6”

does anyone know how it happen and give a hand?

Comment: Neither of these is a UTF8 encoding. The page you see uses UTF8 encoding. `余昌泼` is a UTF8 encoded string. The first string *is* a [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp). The second isn't. IE does *not* encode string by itself though - how was this string generated? What code created either of them?

Comment: apologizes for late reply! thanks for the comments! please see the new screenshot @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: thanks you too! please see the new findings @GeorgeHelyar

Comment: i am sorry i flagged wrongly to your comment, can i remove the flag? i can not find the operation.@GeorgeHelyar